# Elasticsearch: filter documents by array passed in request contains all document array elements

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

My documents stored in elasticsearch have following structure:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "test": "name",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "rule1",
      "ruleDetails": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "requiredAnswerId": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "requiredAnswerId": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "requiredAnswerId": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

where, `rules` property has `nested` type.

I need to query documents by checking that array of `requiredAnswerId` passed in the search request (provided terms) contains all `rules.ruleDetails.requiredAnswerId` stored in the document.

Does anyone know which elasticsearch option I can use to build such specific query? Or maybe, it is better to fetch the whole document and perform filtering on the application level.

**UPDATED**
Adding mapping

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "test": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "rules": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "id": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "ruleDetails": {
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "long"
                },
                "requiredAnswerId": {
                  "type": "long"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Elasticsearch can do this with queries, have you taken a stab at it? You probably want a term query: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Comment: @IanGabes, thanks for you answer. The thing is that as per terms query definition it "Returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided field", but I need to do contains operation vise versa. I want to check that my provided terms contains terms stored in the document.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, I was reading too quickly. I would tend to agree with you, that this work should be done client side. There is some more advanced configuration you can do to get something like this to work, but I am not sure I would reach for this tool first: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html

In my work, i try to avoid nested documents and parent / child as much as possible though : )

Comment: Please add your mapping

Comment: @AlkisKalogeris, mapping added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mapping:**

```
{
  "index4" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "rules" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "ruleDetails" : {
              "properties" : {
                "id" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                },
                "requiredAnswerId" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "test" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:** This will need use of scripts which are not good from performance perspective. I am looping through all documents and checking if field is present is passed parameters

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "rules",
      "query": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "for(a in doc['rules.ruleDetails.requiredAnswerId']){if(!params.Ids.contains((int)a)) return false; }  return true;",
            "params": {
              "Ids": [
                1,
                2,
                3
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
  "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "TxOpvnEBf42mOjxvvLQB",
        "_score" : 4.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "test" : "name",
          "rules" : [
            {
              "id" : 2,
              "name" : "rule1",
              "ruleDetails" : [
                {
                  "id" : 3,
                  "requiredAnswerId" : 1
                },
                {
                  "id" : 4,
                  "requiredAnswerId" : 2
                },
                {
                  "id" : 5,
                  "requiredAnswerId" : 3
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "id" : 3,
              "name" : "rule3",
              "ruleDetails" : [
                {
                  "id" : 3,
                  "requiredAnswerId" : 1
                },
                {
                  "id" : 4,
                  "requiredAnswerId" : 2
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {
          "rules" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 4.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index4",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "TxOpvnEBf42mOjxvvLQB",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "rules",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : 4.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "id" : 2,
                    "name" : "rule1",
                    "ruleDetails" : [
                      {
                        "id" : 3,
                        "requiredAnswerId" : 1
                      },
                      {
                        "id" : 4,
                        "requiredAnswerId" : 2
                      },
                      {
                        "id" : 5,
                        "requiredAnswerId" : 3
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

**EDIT 1**

[Terms_set](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) can be used as an alternative. It will be faster compared to script query

> Returns documents that contain a minimum number of exact terms in a
>   provided field.

minimum_should_match_script- size of array can be used to match the minimum number of passed values.

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "rules",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "terms_set": {
              "rules.ruleDetails.requiredAnswerId": {
                "terms": [
                  1,
                  2,
                  3
                ],
                "minimum_should_match_script": {
                  "source": "doc['rules.ruleDetails.requiredAnswerId'].size()"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. It looks good, but it will not handle the case, when in the request terms I have elements `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, and in the stored document values are `1, 2, 3`. For this case, I need to receive document in the result set as well.

Comment: @I.Domshchikov I don't think this can be done using term queries. I have added script query for this

Comment: @I.Domshchikov i found a better way to resolve your issue. I have added  it in answer under EDIT 1

Comment: jaspreet-chahal, thanks for your initial answer and the updated version. I will try and will get back to you.

Comment: the `terms_set` alternative does what I need. Thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 0):

After some time playing with ES and reading its documentation, I found that you should keep in mind that provided `script` should be compiled and applied for the document, hence it will be slower, if you just know the required number elements that should match in advance.

Therefore, I created a separate field `requiredMatches` that stores the number of `rules.ruleDetails.requiredAnswerId` elements for every document and calculate it before indexing document. Then, instead of using `minimum_should_match_script` in my search query, I am using `minimum_should_match_field`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "rules",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "terms_set": {
              "rules.ruleDetails.requiredAnswerId": {
                "terms": [
                  1,
                  2,
                  3
                ],
                "minimum_should_match_field": "requiredMatches"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I used, [following example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html#terms-set-query-ex-request-query), as a reference